# What is the basis of the vector space $l^\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, normed-spaces, hamel-basis

We know that every vector space has a Hamel basis and also every normed space need not have a Schauder basis. As the normed space $l^\infty$ is not Separable so can't have the Schauder basis, but on the other side $l^\infty$ is also a vector space so what will be the Hamel basis of $l^\infty$?

Comment: The proof that any vector space admits a basis is not constructive in general. There is no way to write down such a basis. It is uncountable.

Comment: This seems, to some extent, related: [A Hamel basis for $l^{\,p}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/194189) and [Is there a constructive way to exhibit a basis for $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/122571)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An indication that you cannot expect *explicit* example is that this cannot be proven in [ZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).

In an infinite-dimensional normed space, existence of Hamel basis implies existence of [discontinuous linear functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99206). And it is consistent with ZF that there are no discontinuous linear functionals on $\ell_\infty$, see here: [On every infinite-dimensional Banach space there exists a discontinuous linear functional.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288075/on-every-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-there-exists-a-discontinuous-linear-f) (Perhaps there is a more straightforward argument, but this is is what I was able to come up with.)

However, if you only want *proof* that $\ell_\infty$ has Hamel basis, it is as standard application of [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma). In fact, every linearly independent set is contained in a basis. (And for this proof there is nothing special about $\ell_\infty$ - it works for any vector space exactly in the same way.)

Comment: Does the Schauder basis of a finite dimensional normed space X is the same as the Hamel basis of X?. For example, the Schauder basis of $R^{n}$?

Comment: If Schauder basis is defined for finite-dimensional spaces at all, them it will be the same as Hamel basis. (It depends on whether in definition of Schauder basis you allow it to be *finite* countable or you require *infinite* countable set/sequence. I am not sure, but I'd guess both possibilities appear in literature.) If you are interested in differences between Hamel and Schauder basis, this might be useful: [What is the difference between a Hamel basis and a Schauder basis?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/630142)

Comment: thanks that was really an informative link to me. How can we define Schauder basis for a finite dimensional normed space as the schauder basis must include the infinite linear combinations?

Comment: You can define it by cases and say that for finite-dimensional you define Schauder base as the usual base. 
This seems to be how they do it in [*Banach Space Theory* by Fabian, Habala et al.](https://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA182), see the remarks right after Definition 4.6. Another possibility would be to formulate the definition in such way that we say that it is either *finite or countable sequence* or that Schauder basis is a countable *set*. (Countable sets include finite sets.) My impression is that when studying Schauder basis, fin.-dim. case is not that interesting.

Answer (score 7):

Even for separable infinite-dimensional Banach spaces a Hamel basis is not something we can exhibit concretely.  It lives out in Axiom-of-Choice land.  Even more so for $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: So what we can say about the space $l^\infty$?

Comment: Why "even more so for $\ell^\infty$"?

Comment: @PrinceKhan it has an *uncountable* Hamel basis, which doesn't have a good representation.

Comment: @Vim how can we prove that $(e_{n})=((0,0,0,...0,1,0,0,...))$ is not the basis of the space $l^\infty$?

Comment: I would like to go to Axiom-of-Choice land...

Comment: @PrinceKhan consider $(1,1,1,\cdots)\in \ell^\infty$ which cannot be finitely spanned by $(e_n)_n$.

Comment: @Vim thats so nice of you.... thanks to all of you

Comment: @PrinceKhan this has nothing to do with convergence. The only reason is that $(1,1,\cdots)$ has infinitely many $1$s and you cannot use only finitely many $e_n$ to add up to it.

Comment: @Vim check please whether I am right?
The sequence $(1,1,1,...) \in l^\infty$ and as the series $\sum \|\| e_{n} \|\|=1+1+1+1...)$.i.e the series $\sum e_{n}$ is not absolutely convergent so $\sum e_{n}$ is not convergent as the space $l^\infty$ is Banach space. Therefore we can say that there does not any sequence of scalars $(x_{n})$ such that $(1,1,1,...)=\sum x_{n}e_{n}$

Comment: @Vim! Thus we can say that $(e_{n})$ is not the Schauder basis of $l^\infty$.

Comment: @PrinceKhan It is. A Schauder basis is not the same as a Hamel basis.

Comment: @Vim! I am talking about Schauder basis, The space $l^\infty$ is not separable so it has no Schauder basis. Therefore $(e_{n})$ should not be the Schauder basis of $l^\infty$. Am I right?

Comment: @PrinceKhan Oh sure.. sorry I made a mistake. You are right it is not a Schaefer basis either.

Comment: But still there is a bit confusion @Vim.
Note that, $(e_{n})$ is a Schauder basis of a normed space X iff there is a unique sequence of scalars $(x_{n})$ such that every $x \in X$ can be written as $x=\sum x_{n}e_{n}$. 
Now note that $(1,1,1....)=\sum 1\times e_{n})$ satisfies above definition, therefore we should have to prove in a different way that $e_{n})$ is not a Schauder basis of $l^\infty$. (In short I am still failed to show that $(e_{n})$ is not the Schauder basis

Comment: $(1,1,...)$ is **not** $\sum e_n$. This might be true in a pointwise sense. We would need it however in the $\ell^\infty$ sense where this is wrong.

Comment: @PrinceKhan well to prove it's not a Schauder basis $(1,1,\cdots)$ already suffices. Note that for *any* $n$, $\|\sum_{k=1}^n c_ke_k-(1,1,\cdots)\|_\infty\ge1> 0.$ So it's impossible to approach $(1,1,\cdots)$ using elements finitely spanned by $\{e_n\}$.

Comment: Yes I got it now completely... Thanks to both of you @Vim and LeBtz