# How to write this vector in terms of Hamel basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(c,c,c,...)$ be a vector  in $l_\infty$, where $c \ne 0$. How to write this vector in terms of Hamel basis?

Comment: Depends which basis. For instance, there is a basis that has $(c,c,c,\ldots)$ as an element, so it's pretty easy in that one.

Comment: As far as I know, nobody has actually "seen/described explicitly" such a Hamel basis. Ah, the miracle of Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that you would be expected to answer such a question. For one, you wouldn't be asked to write $(c,c,c)$ in terms of a basis of $\Bbb{R^3}$ **without being given the basis first**. And, nobody has ever exhibited a Hamel basis of $\ell_\infty$. They only exist by virtue of the Axiom of Choice, you know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the basis of the vector space $l^\infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050769/what-is-the-basis-of-the-vector-space-l-infty)

Comment: @max_zorn ... if you do say so yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly which misconceptions you have here, so I'll just say a few things and hopefully it will clarify.

1. The set $\{(1,0,0,\ldots),(0,1,0,0,\ldots), \ldots\}$ is not a Hamel basis for $l_\infty$ as is evidenced by the fact that $(c,c,\ldots)$ cannot be written as a finite linear combination of those vectors.
2. There is no such thing as *the* Hamel basis. There are generally many of them. There is also not generally a *canonical* basis, so saying "the" doesn't even work implicitly.
3. It is generally impossible to explicitly exhibit a basis (and $l_\infty$ is not an exception), so there's no way to answer your question in any kind of generality. However, from the usual general proof that a basis exists, it's reasonably clear that, for some given element $v$ of your vector space $V,$ that there is a basis that contains $v$ as an element. More generally, for any linearly independent subset $L\subseteq V,$ there is a basis $B$ with $L\subseteq B.$ (The usual argument applies Zorn's lemma to the set of all linearly independent subsets of $V,$ and we can just modify it to instead consider the set of all linearly independent subsets of $V$ that contain $L$ as a subset.) So there are certainly bases in which your vector $(c,c,\ldots)$ has a simple expression.