# Linear transformation bounded iff its kernel is closed in infinite-dimensional Banach spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

I am working on Problem 8, Chapter 6, in Luenberger's *Optimization by Vector Space Methods*. It states:

*"Show that a linear transformation mapping one Banach space into another is bounded if and only if its nullspace is closed."*

I am having a bit of trouble with the converse. In particular, if we let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear transformation, Luenberger doesn't assume that either $X$ or $Y$ be finite-dimensional. Do you have any idea on how to proceed? I have thought (without success) of considering the quotient space $\hat{X}/\ker f$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true in general:

Let $X$ be any infinite-dimensional banach space with (Hamel) basis $B$ and let $\{b_n\}_{n\in\ \mathbb N}$ be a countable subset of $B$. Then define $T:X\to X$ on the basis $B$ by $T(b_n)=nb_n$ and $T(b)=b$ for $b\in B\setminus \{b_n\}_{n\in\ \mathbb N}$ and extend linearly. Then $T$ is an unbounded operator, with $\ker T=\{0\}$ closed.

Comment: I thought so as well, in the first moment -- but then I realized, is it indeed a **map** from a banach space into a banach space? Seems like sometime the image is not well-defined (as an element of the target space).

Comment: @PeterFranek: Sure it is well defined.  Since $B$ is a Hamel basis, every vector in $X$ can be uniquely written as a finite linear combination of the elements of $B$.

Comment: I see. Nice :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept this answer. I have one additional question however: is it possible to construct the $B$ in this counterexample without using the axiom of choice?

Comment: It is not possible using just ZF, there are models of ZF + negation of AC in which every such linear map is continuous, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/288087/256128)

Comment: Very interesting answer, and very interesting link. Thank you all.